# Error al ejecutar consultas SQL con driver API sqlsrv desde PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, php5

Estoy trabajando con *php5* y *SQL Server 2008* montado en un *servidor XAMPP*, instalé el driver para poder trabajar pero me sale el siguiente error cuando lo ejecuto:

**conBD.php**

```
<?php

    $server='x.x.x.x';
    $bd='PruebaO';
    $coninfo= array("Database"=>$bd,"UID"=>"admin","PWD"=>"1234567","CharacterSet"=>"UTF-8");
    $con = sqlsrv_connect($server, $coninfo);

    if($con){

            echo "Conectado a: $bd";
            echo "<br>";echo "<br>";

    }else{

        echo "$bd ",(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));
        echo "<br>";echo "<br>"; 
    }
?>
```

**metodos-BD.php**

```
<?php 
include ("conBD.php");

    $nombre =  $_POST['nom']; 
    $rut = $_POST['rut']; 
    $fono = $_POST['fon']; 
    $correo=$_POST['em'];
    $direcion=$_POST['dire'];
    $cod=$_POST['cod'];

    $comprobar= sqlsrv_query($con,"SELECT   CodAux, NomAux, RutAux, DirAux, FonAux1, EMail  FROM  softland.cwtauxi WHERE(CodAux = '$cod')");
    $fila=sqlsrv_num_rows($comprobar);

        if($fila==0){

            $insertarc=sqlsrv_query($con,"Insert Into softland.CWTAUXI ( CodAux,NomAux,NoFAux,RutAux,ActAux,GirAux,PaiAux,Region,CiuAux,Comaux,Provaux,DirAux,DirNum,DirDpto,CodPostal,FonAux1,FonAux2,FonAux3,CodAreaFon, AnexoFon,FaxAux1,FaxAux2, CodAreaFax,ClaCli,ClaPro,ClaEmp,ClaSoc,ClaDis,ClaOtr,Casilla,Email,WebSite,Bloqueado,BloqueadoPro,Notas,EsReceptorDTE,EMailDTE,CtaCliente,CtaCliMonExt,Usuario,Proceso, Sistema) VALUES ('$cod','$nombre', Null, '$rut', 'S', Null, Null,  Null , Null, '$direcion', Null,'$fono', Null, Null, Null, NUll, 'Null', 'Null',0,0, 'Null', ' Null', 0, 'S','$correo', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', Null, 'N', Null, 'N', 'N', Null , 'N',  Null , NULL, NULL, 'softland', 'Ficha Cliente ERP', 'IW')");

        if($insertarc){

            echo "El vendedor de registro exitosamente en la BD: $bd";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<br>";
          print_r ($_POST);
        }else{    
            echo"Error en ejecución: \n";
            echo "<br>";
            die (print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));
                  echo "<br>";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }else{
        echo "El Cliente ya exite en: $bd";
        while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($comprobar)){
            echo $row['Codigo']."<br>";
            echo $row['Nombre']."<br>";
            echo $row['Rut']."<br>";
            echo $row['Telefono']."<br>";
            echo $row['Email']."<br>";
            echo $row['Direccion']."<br>";
        }
    }
?>
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Clientes nuevos</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <!--<script src="js/Validaciones.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>  onsubmit="return ValidaCamp()"-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="form" method="post"  action="lib/metodos-BD.php" >
      <div class="logo"> <img src="imagenes/logo-oxford.png" width="90%" height="10%"> </div>
      <h2>Ingresar clientes</h2>
      <div class="input_style">
        <input type="text" name="cod" placeholder="Codigo auxiliar" id="cod" >
        <input type="text" name="nom" placeholder="Nombre" id="nom" >
        <input type="text" name="rut" placeholder="Rut" id="rut" >
        <input type="text" name="fon" placeholder="Telofono" id="fon">
        <input type="text" name="em" placeholder="Email" id="em" >
        <input type="text" name="dire" placeholder="Direccion" id="dire" >
        <input type="submit" value="Guardar" id="btn_ingresar" name="btn_ingresar" class="btn" >
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

> Conectado a: PruebaO
>   Error en ejecución:
>   Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 22001 [SQLSTATE] => 22001 [1] => 8152 [code] => 8152 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Los datos de cadena o binarios se truncarían.
>   [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Los datos de cadena o binarios se truncarían. )
>   [1] => Array ( [0] => 01000 [SQLSTATE] => 01000 [1] => 3621 [code] => 3621 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Se terminó la instrucción.
>   [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Se terminó la instrucción. ) )

Ya verifiqué el largo y tipo de campos en la base de daatos, pero no puedo encontrar el error.

Comment: ¿Seguro que tienes instalado el driver correcto para tu entorno y que está todo actualizado?

Comment: Si, de si no fuese el driver correcto el no hubiese podido levantar el servidor

Comment: ¿Has probado con una consulta más sencilla, por ejemplo que inserte o actualice datos de prueba que no sean muy extensos? Puede que en alguna de las consultas intervengan datos demasiado grandes y que antes de operar con ellos tengas que aumentar el tamaño mínimo que el DBMS maneja. Recuerdo haber tenido ese problema en PDO/MySQL con ciertas consultas, era una columna donde yo concatenaba varios resultados de columnas del tipo `TEXT`. O puede que estés intentando insertar datos cuyo tamaño es mayor que el de la columna.

Comment: Llegue a pensar lo mismo asique comente esa parte del codigo y deje que se ejecutara el select pero tampoco,pero probare con un insert mas simple

Comment: Lo que te comento más arriba me ocurrió con una consulta `SELECT`, en la que yo concatenaba mucho texto, de forma que los resultados eran más grandes que el máximo permitido para una columna. Entonces tuve que ejecutar `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len=100000` antes de la consulta. Pero como dije, estoy hablando de MySQL. Ignoro el comportamiento de SQL Server en esos casos. Prueba con un `SELECT` simple, cosa de depurar que no sea un problema del driver. No se descarta, aunque conecte, si no es el driver adecuado puede darte problemas también.

Comment: FUNCIONA! cree una nueva bd (local) con una tabla para realizar un insert mas simple Gracias ahora se que mi codigo esta bueno aunque la validacion para que no se inserten datos iguales no funciona jajaja